# Почему не срабатывает скрипт вывода iFrame?

Tags: php, html, iframe, html5

Доброго времени суток. У меня вопрос по поводу работы iFrame. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает скрипт вывода iFrame.

На самом деле окно формируется, а вот изображение по ссылке не выводится. Причем суть страницы, о которой идет речь, заключается в следующем: 
Мы попадаем на страницу, там выводиться iFrame. Мы можем изменить ширину и высоту iFrame, нажимаем посмотреть. Данные перезаписываются в переменные и выводятся на страницу при помощи POST. Вот тут-то и происходит неприятность. В результате выполнения выводится пустой iFrame, а в коде страницы, если навести на iFrame, то пишет **token contains a reflected xss vector**.

Я никогда ранее с подобным не встречался, подскажите, что предпринять.

```
echo '<iframe width="'.$width.'px" height="'.$height.'>px" src="'.$links.'" frameborder="0" seamless></iframe>';
```

Comment: @SKYnetRTX, в `iframe` контент с Вашего домена? Это я Вас плавно подвожу к заголовку [Content-Security-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy).

Comment: @romeo, наводка хорошая, но мимо цели.
Да, документ, который отображает iFrame, находится на моем сайте. Фишка в том, что при ручном изменении размеров фрейма все работало, а при задании размеров фрейма через форму - нет.
Может, и не правильно, но решил проблему сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема решилась вот так. Теперь при нажатии кнопки "Отправить" вызывается функция, которая производит редирект на эту же страницу, но в URL уже прописаны новые размеры iFrame. Потом при помощи `$_GET` получаем новые размеры и строим фрейм. Да, задача решена, но криво. Однако пока работает, дальнейшую переработку проведу, наверное, потом.